# Apache not responding to configuration changes

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, configuration

I have an Apache server running the latest 2.2 version on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS. I haven't changed most of the configuration. Everything worked fine at start, but now it's not noticing any changes to its configuration.

For example, here is a `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule myfile [F]
Header set X-Asdf rewrite_found
</IfModule>
```

This has no effect at all (even though I do have `mod_rewrite`), nor do any other things in `.htaccess`.

Also, I added this to `httpd.conf`:

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

No effect at all too.

I have tried these things, without any effect:

- `service apache2 reload`
- `service apache2 restart`
- restarting machine
- Adding to `httpd.conf`:

  ```
  <Directory *>
  AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  ```

Apache is still reading the configuration, as any syntax errors made there will report an error at reload.

What might cause this?

**EDIT:**

```
root@my-server:~# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.0.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.0.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)                                       
Syntax OK
```

Comment: What's the output from `apachectl -S`?

Comment: @ShaneMadden Added output.

Comment: Is everything in your `.htaccess` wrapped in the `<IfModule>`?  `httpd.conf` isn't the main config file under Ubuntu, `apache2.conf` is, though it should be used through an `Include`.  What about if you make changes to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`?  You probably shouldn't be using htaccess files anyway, see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when).

Comment: @ShaneMadden Not all is wrapped, and I checked, `apache2.conf` includes `httpd.conf`.

Comment: @ShaneMadden That did it. `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` disabled overriding, so I went there and enabled it. Now it all works. Also, I will use `.htaccess` as I don't want to a) modify the main configuration all the time and then reload as I may not have command line access, b) I may use a user that has no root access and c) I don't want to crowd my `httpd.conf` with rewrites. Add that as an answer ^^

Comment: Can you change `<Directory *>` to `<Directory />`?

Comment: @edvinas.me Already fixed, waiting for answer by ShaneMadden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this answer myself as [Shane Madden](https://serverfault.com/users/72586/shane-madden), who told me this in the comments did not.

The fix is to make the changes to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` instead of `httpd.conf`, as the former is read after the latter and so directives there override.